snapchat login api oauth: something went wrong
I made this url:
https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/oauth2/auth?client_id=0c4xxxxx-a481-xxxx-968a-658780d3562b&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fnew.xxxxxx.com&response_type=code&scope=snapchat-profile-api

And when i paste it in browser i get:

something went wrong

I've tried many things but still it didnt work. Kindly suggest some legit solution.
   snapchatAuthURL := "https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/oauth2/auth"
   params := url.Values{
       "client_id":     {model.SnapchatClientID},
       "redirect_uri":  {model.SnapchatRedirectURI},
       "response_type": {"code"},
       "scope":         {"user.display_name user.bitmoji.avatar"}, // Example scopes
   }
   redirectURL := snapchatAuthURL + "?" + params.Encode()    but in responce i always get html code .

